# Different tooltip text for Sign Up tab

Tags: bug, tooltips, grammar, sign-up

On the page https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup tooltip for Sign Up tab says (emphasis is mine):

> Sign up **to** {SiteName}
>
> [image: sign up to]

Same tab on the page https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery contains tooltip with another text:

> Sign up **for** {SiteName}
>
> [image: sign up for]

**to**, or **for**: that's the question.

Comment: 22 || ! 24, that is the question.

Comment: @TimPost the answer is [`true`](http://ideone.com/csCqT6).